# Palatini formalism

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, general-relativity

I was going through the Palatini formalism in order to obtain the Einstein equations and the fact that the connection $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita one. Using the variational approach, I vary the action integral

$$S=\int \sqrt{-g} g^{ab}R_{ab}d^4x.$$

After some calculations, one obtains that

$$\delta S = \int\sqrt{-g}\big[ \nabla_cW^c-\nabla_cg^{ab}\delta\Gamma^c_{ab} +\nabla_bg^{ab}\delta\Gamma^c_{ac} \big]d^4x,$$

where $W^c = g^{ab}\delta\Gamma^{c}_{ab} - g^{ac}\delta\Gamma^{b}_{ab}.$

The last two terms between the square brackets indeed could be brought to the form $F(g)\delta\Gamma^c_{ab}$ such that $F(g)=0$ implies $\nabla$ is Levi-Civita, but I am struggling to find a trick to make $\sqrt{-g}\nabla_cW^c$ vanish (most probably as a boundary term).

Any help more than welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: I guess that you moved $g$ inside $\nabla$ to get your $W$. But this is illegal, because this depends on metric compatibility, which together with torsion-freeness, leads automatically to the Levi-Civita one.

Comment: A detailed derivation can be found in Lecture Notes on General Relativity by Matthias Blau [here](http://www.blau.itp.unibe.ch/newlecturesGR.pdf). The derivation starts at (20.115).

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it is a boundary term.

By Gauss' theorem $$ \int_U\sqrt{-g}\nabla_a W^a\ d^4x=\int_{\partial U}\sqrt{|h|}n_a W^a\ d^3\xi, $$ where $\xi$ are coordinates on the boundary, $h$ is the determinant on the induced metric on the boundary and $n_a$ is the unit normal vector pointing outwards from the boundary.

In the Palatini-formalism, the metric and the connection are both configuration variables, so boundary conditions can be prescribed for both of them. Thus, if $\delta\Gamma|_{\partial U}=0$ is prescribed, then $W|_{\partial U}=0$, thus the term vanishes.

---

EDIT: I have a bit of a hard time adapting to your derivation, so I'll do it my way. This may or may not directly answer your question, but will most likely solve your problem.

- The difference between two connections is a tensor field. Let $\nabla$ denote the dynamical connection, and $\hat{\nabla}$ the Levi-Civita connection. Then $$ \nabla_XY=\hat{\nabla}_XY+C(X,Y). $$
- We will use $C$ to represent the connection $\nabla$. It is clear that the variation of $\nabla$ is the same as the variation of $C$. It is less clear, but even if the LC connection is used as the reference connection, it doesn't get varied when the metric is. Why? Because an *arbitrary* connection can be used as a reference connection, we can always use the LC connection belonging to the *unperturbed metric*.
- For arbitrary auxiliary vector field $X$, we have $\delta\nabla_a X^b=\delta A^b_{\ ac}X^c$, where $A$ are the connection coefficients of $\nabla$, but we also have $\delta\nabla_a X^b=\delta(\hat{\nabla}_aX^b+C^b_{\ ac}X^c)=\delta C^b_{\ ac}X^c$, so we can simply take $C$ as the connection variable.

The curvature tensor of $\nabla$ (which I'll denote with $F$ instead of $R$) can be expresse with the curvature tensor of the LC connection as $$ F^c_{\ dab}=R^c_{\ dab}+\hat\nabla_aC^c_{\ bd}-\hat\nabla_bC^c_{\ ad}+C^c_{\ ae}C^e_{\ bd}-C^c_{\ be}C^e_{\ ad}.$$ Variation passes through the LC connection unimpeded, so $$ \delta F^c_{\ dab}=\hat\nabla_a\delta C^c_{\ bd}-\hat\nabla_b\delta C^c_{\ ad}+\delta C^c_{\ ae}C^e_{\ bd}+C^c_{\ ae}\delta C^e_{\ bd}-(a\leftrightarrow b), $$

$$ \delta F_{ab}=\hat\nabla_c\delta C^c_{\ ab}-\hat\nabla_b\delta C^c_{\ ca}+\delta C^c_{\ ce}C^e_{\ ab}+C^c_{\ ce}\delta C^e_{\ ab}-\delta C^c_{\ be}C^e_{\ ca}-C^c_{\ be}\delta C^e_{\ ca} $$ $$ g^{ab}\delta F_{ab}= ... $$

I don't want to go on from here on because this is getting too long, but 1) I think if you expand your $\nabla_c g_{ab}$s in terms of $\hat\nabla$, you'll get the same terms as I do (except for the parts containing the covariant derivatives), 2) I'll do the part involving the covariants: $$ g^{ab}(\hat\nabla_c\delta C^c_{\ ab}-\hat\nabla_b\delta C^c_{\ ca})=\hat\nabla_c\delta C^c_{ab}g^{ab}-\hat\nabla_c\delta C^b_{\ ba}g^{ac}=\hat\nabla_c W^c. $$ But here now it is the LC connection that appears, and Gauss' theorem can be utilized.

Comment: Using Harvey Reall's Lecture Notes on GR http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/hsr1000/part3_gr_lectures_2016.pdf p117, isn't it required for $\nabla$ to be Levi-Civita? This is actually what we are looking to prove.

Comment: Oh damn, I'm an idiot. I'll think about this and update my post.

Comment: @Marius Post edited.